# Finding all elements greater than current element in a list

Tags: python, list, numpy, loops, indexing

If I have an array in Python in which all of the elements have different values, e.g. `[1,4,6,2,10,3,5]`,
is there a way to find the total number of values in the list that are greater than the current index?

So for example, using the above list of length 7, the result I'd like to get is another list of length 7 which looks like `[6,3,1,5,0,4,2]`. I was having trouble trying to loop through the list (the code I tried to use is below)

```
for i in data:
    count = np.sum(data > data[i])
    N[i]=count
```

where `data` is the array containing all the pertaining values and `N` is an `np.zeros` list of the same length as data

Comment: You need to be precise: are you working withs lists or with numpy arrays?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were very close. `for i in data` iterates through each *element*, not the indices as in Java/C.

Use `range(len(data))` instead.

```
import numpy as np

data = np.array([1,4,6,2,10,3,5])
out = np.array([0]*7)

for i in range(len(data)):
    count = np.sum(data > data[i])
    out[i] = count

print(out)  # [6 3 1 5 0 4 2]
```

Another way to write the loop is to use `enumerate()`, which returns an iterator of pairs of (indices, elements).

```
for i, x in enumerate(data):
    count = np.sum(data > x)
    out[i] = count
```

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Ah yes, good call. Amended.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my suggestion:

We sort the original list (l) and save it in a new list m. We create a new list (k) where we save the count of elements that are found on the right of the position of each element in m. See below:

```
l=[1,4,6,2,10,3,5]

m=sorted(l)
#[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 10]

k=[]
for i in l:
    k.append(len(m)-m.index(i)-1)

>>> print(k)

[6, 3, 1, 5, 0, 4, 2]
```

Comment: Don't use `.index` in a loop like that, use `enumerate` to iterate over an index and a value, or heck, even just manually keep track of the index yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
list = [1,4,6,2,10,3,5]
list2 = []
v = len(list)
for x in list:
    if x > v:
        pass
    else:
        list2.append(x)

print(list2)
```

EDIT `¯\_(ツ)_/¯` (To see the total number of elements greater than the current element)

```
list = [1,4,6,2,10,3,5]
list2 = []
v = len(list)
total = 0

for x in list:
    if x > v:
        pass
    else:
        list2.append(x)

for y in list2:
    total += 1

list2 = str(list2).replace('[', '')
list2 = list2.replace(']', '')

print("Now - " + list2 + ", in total of " + str(total) + " numbers ;)")
```

Output -

```
Now - 1, 4, 6, 2, 3, 5, in total of 6 numbers ;)
```

Comment: I believe this finds all the values in the list smaller than the length of the list? I'm not sure this was exactly what I was looking for (as I wanted to see the total number of elements greater than the current element and then loop through) but thanks anyway!

Comment: Oh, sorry, I didn't catch that) I'll update my code

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can do it by using `vectorize` as follows:

```
>>> data = np.array( [1,4,6,2,10,3,5] )
>>> np.vectorize(lambda a, b : np.sum(a>b), excluded = [0] )(data, data)
array([6, 3, 1, 5, 0, 4, 2])
```